# Japanese Text is not show properly

Tags: windows, fonts, regional-settings, cjk

My collegue wants to use my application in Japan. Therefore I tested the application in Windows 7 and changed the Regional Settings for "non-unicode"-Language to Japanese.

Now I have the problem, that some text are shown right with japanese characters. Other text is displayed with wrong characters (not japanese).

I tested also other languages like Chinese or Taiwanese and every text is right. I have only problems with Japanese.

Has anybody an idea what's wrong?

Comment: A lot of potential things could be wrong. Please post a sample of code that renders text which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely because of the "Unihan" principle being applied by Unicode, which forced similarly-looking Japanese and Chinese letters to be encoded into same Unicode character despite their glyph being difference. Many computer systems would use Chinese font instead of Japanese font by default so the Chinese font would be displayed, hence it would result in wrong glyph. Changing the "non-unicode-language" into Japanese would not solve such a problem.

In order to display the proper Japanese glyph, you need to make sure that your application is going to use a Japanese font. Normally if your program is to run in an entirely Japanese environment which include changing the default language and font of the computer into Japanese then Japanese font would be used. On the other hand, you can also specify or embed a Japanese font for your application to make sure it would work as intended.